# How to migrate Data From Ms access to Derby Database or How to migrate Data from My sql to Derby Database

Tags: mysql, ms-access, derby, sql-scripts

I have used many tools but they not work correctly and when i start migration process, they generate the `Null value error`. Also I have tried to migrate using`Sql script` to insert data in derby table but they not work it.

**So basically my question is: How do we migrate Data From one DB to Other?**

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow!  You can take the [tour] first and learn [ask] a good question and create a [mcve].  That makes it easier for us to help you.

Answer (score 1):

A very simple way would be to [Export Mysql Database into a CSV File](http://www.debianadmin.com/export-mysql-database-into-a-csv-file.html) and than,

import it to derby database using [Derby Import Tool](http://www.razorsql.com/features/derby_import.html).

you can also import your CSV data into Derby with something like this as explained in this [blog](http://lugerpitt.blogspot.in/2008/08/importing-spreadsheet-data-into.html):

```
CALL SYSCS_UTIL.SYSCS_IMPORT_TABLE (null, 'Sampletable', 'Sampledata.csv',  ';', null, null, 0);
```

**UPDATE**: Also refer Jad [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/25065589/5588347) as well as the posts: [mysql dump into derby](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3693170/mysql-dump-into-derby) and [MySQL dump .sql script and import to an apache derby](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3751425/mysql-dump-sql-script-and-import-to-an-apache-derby).

You can read [this](http://db.apache.org/derby/integrate/db_ddlutils.html) article which says: Install the most current official release of [Apache Derby](http://db.apache.org/derby/derby_downloads.html).

You can also get a specific version [here](http://www.java2s.com/Code/Jar/d/Downloadderbyclientjar.htm).

Comment: i want to try this one  but i have migration multiple data approx 250 table , i think Derby import tool migrate only one Table and i have download the import tool from here http://razorsql.com/download_win.html this one correct ? i want to create  derby database in netbeans.

Comment: if derby database tools install any else not in netbeans  so if possible send me the Download link.